# What are width and height parameters for in java.awt.Component.getBaseline(int, int)?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Java API documentation doesn't have a lot of information about this. Could someone shed some light on this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of this method is the offset of the font baseline from the top of the component. This value depends on the size of the component - changing the width may cause text in the component to be wrapped, and changing the height will cause the text to shift if it's aligned to the bottom of the component.

Since this method is used during component layout, it can't use the actual component size and position to calculate the baseline, because the component is being resized and repositioned during the layout. Therefore, the size is passed directly to the method. That's what the `width` and `height` parameters are for.

Answer (score 3):

A Compopnent may compute its baseline differently based on its size. Those parameters are there so a container's layout manager can ask a child Component "If I make your size width x height, what will your baseline value be?" This answer might be needed by the LayoutManager in order to try to align text baselines of various children.